# DropDownList content overwrite

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM User_Reg WHERE User_ID='" + UserId + "'";
           DataTable dataTablerepeaterUserList = null;
           dataTablerepeaterUserList =objSqlDbComm.ExecuteDatasetQuery(strSQL).Tables[0];


foreach (DataRow dr in dataTablerepeaterUserList.Rows)
{   
   ddlTitle.SelectedItem.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
}


 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTitle" runat="server" CssClass="csstextbox" >
      <asp:ListItem>Mr.</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Mrs.</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Miss.</asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem>Dr.</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

If, suppose,  dr["Title"]=Dr.  Then it is overwrite Mr. with Dr. and got result like:

```
| Dr.  |
| Mrs. |
| Miss.|
| Dr.  |
```

I am passing User_ID from `View_User.aspx` to `Create_User.aspx` for edit user purpose using querystring.  Id getting proper, showing all correct fields in `Create_User.aspx`.  All controls get correct data properly. But when I populate title of current user then it overwrite with first item of `DropDownList`.  (I have only problem with `DropDownList` it is overwritten).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just set `Dr.` as the selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code, is that you are just overwriting the `.text` property of the first `ListItem` in the `DropDownList`.

What you want to do is find the existing `ListItem` that you want, and modifies the `SelectedIndex` property of the `DropDownList` so that the proper item is selected.  This should work for you:

```
// Find the correct list item in the drop down based on your data
ListItem theItemYouWant = ddlTitle.Items.FindByText(dr["Title"].ToString());
// Change the selected index to that items index
ddlTitle.SelectedIndex = ddlTitle.Items.IndexOf(theItemYouWant);
```

---

As a side note, you should not concatenate strings in your SQL, like in your example.  This leaves you open to SQL Injection attacks.  Instead you should use parameters, like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM User_Reg WHERE User_ID = @User_ID";
```

And then add "@User_ID" as a parameter to wherever you're executing your query.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly with your code does:

By default, the first element of the drop down list is the selected one, and you're overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

as you are getting data for particular user by userid you will get a single record. So need to use for loop for dataTablerepeaterUserList.
Just check if row exists then use it.
like

```
if (dataTablerepeaterUserList.rows.count > 0)
{
     ForEach(ListItem  itm  In ddlTitle.Items)
     {
            If (itm.Text = dataTablerepeaterUserList.Rows[0].tostring())
            {
                  itm.Selected = True;
            }
     }
}
```